# getting an error when trying to use place_forget on a frame widget(Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, global

When I try to call .place_forget, it gives me the following error:

```
 newframe.place_forget()
```

NameError: name 'newframe' is not defined
I do not know what is causing the error, as I made the variable global. Any response will be appreciated! This is the code related to the problem:

```
def frame():
    newframe = Frame(window, bg=color, bd=5, relief=SUNKEN)
    newframe.place(rely=0.5, relx=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
    Button(newframe, text='close', font=('Comic Sans', 30), command=closeframe).pack()


def closeframe():
    global newframe
    newframe.place_forget()
```

Comment: `global newframe` should come right after `def frame():`

Comment: @TheLizzard Thanks for the feedback! I was stuck on this for way to long.